# How the Redirect is happen in magento2 customer account controller?

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect

How Magento redirect the customer to account login controller form the account index controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should check [`Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php#L15) and check the [`beforeDispatch()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php#L46-L58) method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which is responsible for redirecting the customer to the specified location after successful login.

```
    if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
         $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
         $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
         // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
         $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
         return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

You can find the details in execute method in file `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php`